# Can Solr or ElasticSearch return same results in different orders to different visitors for the same search criteria?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

I am developing a Spring-based website and I need to use a search engine to provide "customized" search results. I am considering Solr or Elastic.

Here is what I mean by "customized".

Suppose I have two fields A and B to search against.

Suppose that there are two visitors and I am able to profile them by tracking their activities. Suppose visitor 1 constantly uses or searches for value a (of A) and visitor 2 value b (of B). Now both visitors search for records that satisfy A=a OR B=b.

Can Solr or Elastic return results in different order for visitor 1 and 2? I mean that for example, results with A=a are ahead of only B=b results for visitor 1? And the opposite for visitor 2?

I understand that I need to pass some signal to a search engine to ask the engine to give more "weight" to one of the fields.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to give a different weight to the fields you're querying on depending on the user that's executing the query.

You could for example use a [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/) query with elasticsearch, which allows you to search on multiple fields giving them different weights as well. Here is an example that makes the `fieldA` more important:

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "this is a test",
    "fields" : [ "fieldA^3", "fieldB" ]
  }
}
```

That way the score is influenced by the weights that you put on the query, and if you sort by score (default) you get the results in the expected order. The weights assigned to the fields need some fine-tuning though depending on your documents and the query you execute.

Comment: javanna, thanks sooo much for your input. I will look into this. again, thanks!